# Order of execution of Future - Making sequential inserts in a db non-blocking

Tags: scala, cassandra, functional-programming, apache-kafka, akka-stream

A simple scenario here. I am using akka streams to read from kafka and write into an external source, in my case: cassandra.

Akka streams(reactive-kafka) library equips me with backpressure and other nifty things to make this possible.

kafka being a Source and Cassandra being a Sink, when I get bunch of events which are, for example be cassandra queries here through Kafka which are supposed to be executed sequentially (ex: it could be a INSERT, UPDATE and a DELETE and must be sequential).

I cannot use `mayAsync` and execute both the statement, Future is eager and there is a chance that DELETE or UPDATE might get executed first before INSERT.

I am forced to use Cassandra's `execute` as opposed to `executeAsync` which is non-blocking.

There is no way to make a complete async solution to this issue, but how ever is there a much elegant way to do this?

For ex: Make the Future lazy and sequential and offload it to a different execution context of sorts. 
`mapAsync` gives a parallelism option as well.

Can Monix Task be of help here?

This a general design question and what are the approaches one can take.

UPDATE:

```
Flow[In].mapAsync(3)(input => {

 input match {
    case INSERT => //do insert - returns future
    case UPDATE => //do update - returns future
    case DELETE => //delete - returns future
}
```

The scenario is a little more complex. There could be thousands of insert, update and delete coming in order for specific key(s)(in kafka)
I would ideally want to execute the 3 futures of a single key in sequence. I believe Monix's Task can help?

Comment: Seems you want to create buffers while key remains unchanged and then execute actions on resulting buffers in strict sequence. I know how to do it using Monix `Observable`, but not Akka streams tho :c

Comment: I see Monix Observable is quite similar to akka streams.  The problem I am stating above should be a common problem when dealing with sequence and async.

Comment: Have you considered just using Kafka's Connect API to stream your data from Kafka to Cassandra?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt support backpressure. Akka streams or Monix Observable are reactive and backpressure enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you process things with parallelism of 1, they will get executed in strict sequence, which will solve your problem.

But that's not interesting. If you want, you can run operations for different ***keys*** in parallel - if processing for different keys is independent, which, I assume from your description, is possible. To do this, you have to buffer the incoming values and then regroup it. Let's see some code:

```
import monix.reactive.Observable
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import monix.eval.Task

// Your domain logic - I'll use these stubs
trait Event
trait Acknowledgement // whatever your DB functions return, if you need it
def toKey(e: Event): String = ???
def processOne(event: Event): Task[Acknowledgement] = Task.deferFuture {
  event match {
    case _ => ??? // insert/update/delete
  }
}

// Monix Task.traverse is strictly sequential, which is what you need
def processMany(evs: Seq[Event]): Task[Seq[Acknowledgement]] =
  Task.traverse(evs)(processOne)

def processEventStreamInParallel(source: Observable[Event]): Observable[Acknowledgement] =
  source
    // Process a bunch of events, but don't wait too long for whole 100. Fine-tune for your data source
    .bufferTimedAndCounted(2.seconds, 100)
    .concatMap { batch =>
      Observable
        .fromIterable(batch.groupBy(toKey).values) // Standard collection methods FTW
        .mapAsync(3)(processMany) // processing up to 3 different keys in parallel - tho 3 is not necessary, probably depends on your DB throughput
        .flatMap(Observable.fromIterable) // flattening it back
    }
```

The `concatMap` operator here will ensure that your chunks are processed sequentially as well. So even if one buffer has `key1 -> insert, key1 -> update` and the other has `key1 -> delete`, that causes no problems. In Monix, this is the same as `flatMap`, but in other Rx libraries `flatMap` might be an alias for `mergeMap` which has no ordering guarantee.

---

This can be done with `Future`s too, tho there's no standard "sequential traverse", so you have to roll your own, something like:

```
def processMany(evs: Seq[Event]): Future[Seq[Acknowledgement]] =
  evs.foldLeft(Future.successful(Vector.empty[Acknowledgement])){ (acksF, ev) =>
    for {
      acks <- acksF
      next <- processOne(ev)
    } yield acks :+ next
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use akka-streams subflows, to group by key, then merge substreams if you want to do something with what you get from your database operations:

```
def databaseOp(input: In): Future[Out] = input match {
  case INSERT => ...
  case UPDATE => ...
  case DELETE => ...
}

val databaseFlow: Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] =
  Flow[In].groupBy(Int.maxValues, _.key).mapAsync(1)(databaseOp).mergeSubstreams
```

Note that order from input source won't be kept in output as it is done in `mapAsync`, but all operations on the same key will still be in order.

Comment: Will `groupBy` be safe from memory perspective? I think substreams of it will never complete and so never will be GC'd.

Comment: This does look like a nice solution, getting substreams for each key per partition. I already have different stream running for different partition, so this would further create substream for each key. 

yes, memory is one concern. and just to confirm, `mayAsync`s parallelism must always be 1 in this scenario right?

Comment: also, how do you deal with a failure per key in a partition. If i have 1000 users in one partition being served and dont want one key(sub-stream) causing problems to other 999 users. (sorry, a generic design question)
I typically run this stream in child actor which holds a list of failed keys and bypass data for that key into another topic, until its fixed and materialized. Cannot afford to mess up kafka's source topic commits(will affect exactly once delivery semantics)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Future.flatMap`:

```
def doSomething: Future[Unit]
def doSomethingElse: Future[Unit]

val result = doSomething.flatMap { _ => doSomethingElse }
```

This executes the first function, and then, when its `Future` is satisfied, starts the second one. The `result` is a new `Future` that completes when the result of the second execution is satisfied.

The result of the first future is passed into the function you give to `.flatMap`, so the second function can depend on the result of the first one. For example:

```
def getUserID: Future[Int]
def getUser(id: Int): Future[User]

val userName: Future[String] = getUserID.flatMap(getUser).map(_.name)
```

You can also write this as a `for-comprehension`:

```
for {
  id <- getUserID
  user <- getUser(id)
} yield user.name
```

Comment: I am aware of flatmapping and chaining futures. But I ideally pattern match the input event and depending on the type I execute it. Let me update the question.

Comment: Now I don't know what you are talking about. If you want to pattern match, then you should ... well ... patten match. What's the question?

Comment: The scenario is clear with an example above. You get a stream of events in order and you want to insert them into another external system(cassandra in this case) in the same order. A pattern match is used to choose the operation. There are chances where the second event in seq gets executed first before the first one.

Comment: If you want them executed in order, you `flatMap`. 
If you want to pattern match, you pattern match (inside `flatMap`).